# How to disable Eclipse HTML validation via M2E

Tags: eclipse, m2e

I have this project that contains some HTML templates in src/webapp. Those templates have freemarker placeholders like

```
<# something %>
```

which make Eclipse complain about unclosed tags.

Is there anything that I could configure in M2E plugin to instruct Eclipse to skip validation of those files?

Answer (score 1):

Try to uncheck some `html` validations in `eclipse` using this:

```
Window > Preferences > Validation
```

Comment: So, is this the only way? It sucks to tell all 15 developers in the company to do this.